# Icenium/phonegap ios push notifications and php handling

Tags: php, ios, cordova, push-notification

I am using Icenium and Apache Cordova to build an iOS app and I am looking into push notifications.

I have seen [this](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) plugin for phonegap push notifications however I have not found one for icenium or is it platform independent? Or is there a way within Apache Cordova/icenium/Kendo ui/jQ mobile to do this?

I would assume that PHP will handle a request somewhere on a server. What I am looking for is lets say.. user wants to be notified when the value of column example in a database equals 3 (user defined) for it to notify them eg:

id   example

1       : 4

2      : 3

3     :  3

4    :   2345

id 2 and 3 will be sent as and when they are inserted into the table. I will do an SQL query and send it via JSON but what would initialise this process?

This is my first time building an app properly. If there are any good tutorials out there for it I would love to see them; so far I haven't found many. It's more the layout that causes me issues and styling it and making it feel 'right'.

Note, icenium and phonegap do not use Objective C but rather javascript, html, css and php (on server)

Comment: I wonder know do you have to pay $99 to develop iOS and install on the actual iphone device, if not, can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: To get an app into the iOS app store you have to pay the $99 and you'll HAVE to use an Mac for development.

Comment: PhoneGap USES objective-C. But the app-developer may come arround using it. If the app is built by build.phonegap.com In that case you may develop the app without a mac. (You''ll still need to ppay 99$)

Answer (score 5):

Full disclosure: I'm a part of the team behind Icenium.

We have released a new version which includes the [generic Push Notification plugin](https://github.com/bobeast/PushPlugin) on iOS and Android. Release notes [here](http://docs.icenium.com/release-notes/v1-3#pushplugin-support).

Answer (score 3):

This example for icenium may help you with notifications. https://github.com/Icenium/sample-notification

@Christian, this is NOT true, you DO NOT NEED to have a mac with Icenium.  $99 for Apple dev profile, which then goes into iTunes for the cert, then into the Icenium Mist platform, then using Icenium iTunes connect you deploy to app store. See this how to: http://docs.icenium.com/working-with-devices/apple-ios-devices/how-to-create-and-install-your-developer-provisioning-profile-and-certificate

Then this one: http://docs.icenium.com/icenium-mobile-app-development/using-icenium-mist/publishing-with-mist

Icenium also offers a wrapper from the app store call ION - used for testing on the iPHone handset, very cool..

Icenium is the way to go, 3 apps later and we are moving on with this as our platform of choice.

<== ** UPDATE ** ==>
Try the new plugin - https://github.com/Icenium/PushPlugin

Comment: I think the "push notifications" that @zomboble is asking about and the type of notifications in icenium/sample-notification are quite a bit different. Push notifications on icenium right now is... a little rough, I'm finding. But I'm glad you hear about your experience with icenium -- I'm using it for the first time now, and haven't released the app yet, so it's encouraging to hear a success story! :)

Comment: Update: Cordova Push plugin is now available see my edit above